# Best way to redisplay login prompt

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a simple Python (shell) program that asks for input.  What I am looking for is a certain length (len) of a string.  If the string is NOT that minimum, I want to throw an exception and take the user back to the input prompt to try again (for only a given amount of tries, say 3).

my code is basically so far

```
x=input("some input prompt: ")
if len(x) < 5:
print("error message")
count=count+1 #increase counter
```

etc...

-- This is where I am stuck, I want the error to be thrown and then go back to my input... kind of new to Python, so help is greatly appreciated.  This is going to be part of a script on a Linux box.

Comment: The programming language in the title is redundant. That's what the first tag is for.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with a `while` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops work well for this.

You also probably want to use `raw_input` instead of input.  The input function parses and runs the input as python. I'm guessing you are asking users for a password of sorts and not a python command to run.

Also in python there is no i++, use i += 1 for example.

With a while loop:

```
count = 0
while count < number_of_tries:
    x=raw_input("some input prompt: ") # note raw_input
    if len(x) < 5:
        print("error message")
        count += 1    #increase counter ### Note the different incrementor
    elif len(x) >= 5:
       break

if count >= number_of_tries:
    # improper login
else:
    # proper login
```

or with a for loop:

```
for count in range(number_of_tries):
    x=raw_input("some input prompt: ")  # note raw_input
    if len(x) < 5:
        print("error message") # Notice the for loop will
    elif len(x) >= 5:          # increment your count variable *for* you ;)
       break

if count >= number_of_tries-1: # Note the -1, for loops create 
    # improper login           # a number range out of range(n)from 0,n-1
else:
    # proper login
```

Comment: That was along the lines of what I was thinking.  so if I didn't care about number of tries, just the elseif to go on?

Comment: @MikeNeedham Yeah, if you want them to try forever you could use the while loop as something like `while 1:` and it will keep asking until they enter something with length of more than 5

Answer (score 0):

You want a `while` loop instead of your `if`, so you can keep asking for another input as many times as is appropriate:

```
x = input("some input prompt: ")
count = 1
while len(x) < 5 and count < 3:
    print("error message")
    x = input("prompt again: ")
    count += 1 # increase counter

# check if we have an invalid value even after asking repeatedly
if len(x) < 5:
    print("Final error message")
    raise RunTimeError() # or raise ValueError(), or return a sentinel value

# do other stuff with x
```